# Creating C# like List in JavaScript / Jquery / NodeJS

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, node.js, list

I want to create C# like list in JavaScript. In C# we can say `List<string> ListName = new List<string>();`

And then it allows you to add N number of members to the list by using add method.

```
ListName.add("1");
ListName.add("2");
..
..
ListName.add("N");
```

How can I create similar list in JavaScript.

I was thinking of using array but it forces me to specify the size.

```
var a = new Array(5); 
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]; 
var a = new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: i just want to know something you managed to learn C# and having trouble using the basic in javascript? you might need a bacic javascript tutorial

Comment: @Phoenix: Very valid point. But I declared array like this var a = [] and was able to push the data. But while accessing I was not able to retrieve the value. And I got confused. It turned out that I added a semicolon in front of for loop and values were printed as undefined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var someArray = [];
someArray .push(elem);
```

that's all.

P.S. There are also lots of interesting things. So, I advise you to check [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: How do I retrieve this value using for loop?

Comment: you can retrieve this by using plain for loop either array's foreach.


for (var i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {console.log(someArray[i]) }

Comment: I created this fiddle   http://jsfiddle.net/RhUc9/ . What is wrong with it? I am not able to access by array[i]. This is the whole reason I posted this question

Comment: Actually I don't see any fiddle in this topic.

Comment: remove semicolon after for statement

Comment: Thank you. I am so embarrassed now :(

Comment: That's ok. :) Good luck with JS. It's a really powerful language. I picked JS half year ago, and I really like it. (a java developer)

Answer (score 0):

```
var listName = [];
listName.push("1");
listName.push("2");
..
..
listName.push("N");         // At this step listName = ["1", "2", ... "N"]
```

Then you can loop through array items like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < listName.length; i++)
{
    console.log(listName[i]);
}
```

Comment: How do I retrieve the value?? var a = [];
a.push(1);
a.push(2);
for(i =0; i < a.length; i++);
{
    console.log(a.length);
    console.log(a[i]);
}

Comment: You have already written how you can retrieve items from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Nope in javascript also you can declare a array like

```
    var yourarr=[];
```

this will create a dynamic array and then you can add value in it like

```
      yourarr.push(value1);
      yourarr.push(value2);
       .
       .
     yourarr.push(valueN);
```

And also pop them out as
           yourarr.pop();

this will pop out last value from the array and you can also use indexing to retrieve value and perform on them.

And it dynamic no need to give any Size.